# How to extract common rows between multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, intersection

I have data frames like these:
df1:

```
 V1 V2
1 a  b
2 c  d
3 a  e
```

df2:

```
 V1 V2
1 a  b
2 c  e
3 a  f
```

df3:

```
 V1 V2
1 a  b
2 c  f
3 a  m
```

Each data frame has no duplicated rows. I hope to extract common rows among these data frames:
df:

```
 V1 V2 
1 a  b
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `inner_join` from `dplyr`:

First, we join `df1` and `df2`, keeping only rows that are the same between them. This is called an inner join (thus the name of the function). By default, all columns that are named the same are joined. Thus, `df1$V1` is joined to `df2$V1` and `df1$V2` is joined to `df2$V2`. Next, we repeat the same process with the join of `df1` and `df2` with `df3`.

Note that the pipe operator (`%>%`) provides the output of the left hand side as the first argument as the right hand side.

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1,df2) %>%
  inner_join(df3)
#  V1 V2
#1  a  b
```

Also note that if the columns are named differently in the `data.frame`s that you can explicitly define the relationship:

```
inner_join(df1,df2, by = c("V1" = "V1", "V2" = "V2"))
```

Answer (score 4):

A flexible way of doing this (no matter how many dataframes you are lookig at) can be reached using `{purrr:reduce}`. Just put your dataframes in a list and reduce them  applying `inner_join`.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 <- tribble(
    ~V1, ~V2,
    "a", "b",
    "c", "d",
    "a", "e"
)

df2 <- tribble(
    ~V1, ~V2,
    "a", "b",
    "c", "e",
    "a", "f"
)

df3 <- tribble(
    ~V1, ~V2,
    "a", "b",
    "c", "f",
    "a", "m"
)

# Put all data frames in a list
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

reduce(df_list, inner_join)
#> Joining, by = c("V1", "V2")
#> Joining, by = c("V1", "V2")

#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   V1    V2   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This solution is perfect if you have different lengths of dataframes tpo. I have tried, and it works perfectly.

`df1 = data.frame(genes = c('gene1', 'gene3', 'gene4', 'gene2'))
df2 = data.frame(genes = c('gene3', 'gene2', 'gene5', 'gene1', "genet"))
df3 = data.frame(genes = c('gene6', 'gene3', 'gene1', 'gdene7', 'genex', "gene2"))
dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3)
reduce(dfList, inner_join)`

Answer (score 1):

When *each data frame has no duplicated rows* you can use `merge` to *extract common rows between multiple dataframes*:

```
merge(merge(df1, df2), df3)
#  V1 V2
#1  a  b

#Reduce(merge, list(df1, df2, df3)) #Alternative in case there are more than 3 tables
```