# How to find common things from all three column in r?

Tags: r

I have 1000 of genes listed in 3 columns (excel file). I want to find the genes which are common in all the three columns and generate another file with all the these genes name.
Any help would be appreciated. I am comfortable with basic r and python.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please do not ask to solve a programming problem in two unrelated languages on Stack Overflow. Since you've got and accepted R answers I've edited the question to have only R in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you can use `Reduce` + `intersect` to get common values from all the columns.

```
common_genes <- Reduce(intersect, df)
common_genes
#[1] "gene1" "gene3"

write.csv(data.frame(common_genes), 'common_genes.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

**Sample data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('gene1', 'gene3', 'gene4', 'gene2'), 
                 b = c('gene3', 'gene2', 'gene5', 'gene1'), 
                 c = c('gene6', 'gene3', 'gene1', 'gdene7'))

df
#      a     b      c
#1 gene1 gene3  gene6
#2 gene3 gene2  gene3
#3 gene4 gene5  gene1
#4 gene2 gene1 gdene7
```

Comment: Thank Ronak. I will keep this in mind. However, it worked perfectly. My code is- 
##import data 
data_c <- read.csv('up.csv', header = TRUE)

##find common genes
common_genes <- Reduce(intersect, data_c)
write.csv(data.frame(common_genes), 'common_genes.csv', row.names = FALSE)

Comment: This solution is good but not suitable for several dataframes with different lengths. If you are in this case, you can use `reduce` from `purrr` package and `inner_join` from `dplyr` package. See here one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62265614/13997761

Answer (score 1):

to get your data into R you can save as csv from excel then use read_delim(FILENAME, delim = ",") to get your data.

```
library(tidyverse)

# creates a data frame with three columns each column has 1000 values 
# each value is a random number from 1-9

gene_data <- data.frame(column1 = sample(1:9, 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                        column2 = sample(1:9, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                        column3 = sample(1:9, 1000, replace = TRUE))

gene_data_filtered <- gene_data %>% filter(column1 == column2, 
                     column1 == column3)

matched_genes <- gene_data_filtered %>%
  pull(column1) %>% 
  unique()
```