# How to find common and unique elements across multiple data-frames

Tags: r

**Objective** To see the common elements that is my row which are basically gene name in my different comparisons.

This was the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265356/how-to-extract-common-rows-between-multiple-dataframes) which I tried to follow.

```
df1 = data.frame(genes = c('gene1', 'gene3', 'gene4', 'gene2'))
df2 = data.frame(genes = c('gene3', 'gene2', 'gene5', 'gene1', "genet"))
df3 = data.frame(genes = c('gene6', 'gene3', 'gene4', 'gdene7', 'genex', "gene10"))
dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3) 

reduce(dfList, inner_join)
reduce(dfList, inner_join)
Joining, by = "genes"
Joining, by = "genes"
  genes
1 gene3
```

This fails in this case

```
    df1 = data.frame(genes = c('gene1', 'gene3', 'gene4', 'gene2'))
    df2 = data.frame(genes = c('gene3', 'gene2', 'gene5', 'gene1', "genet"))
    df3 = data.frame(genes = c('gene6', 'gene13', 'gene4', 'gdene7', 'genex', "gene10"))
    dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3) 
    
    reduce(dfList, inner_join)

educe(dfList, inner_join)
Joining, by = "genes"
Joining, by = "genes"
[1] genes
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Now how to address this problem. I gave a small set I have like 15 comparison.

```
Expected output 
  gene3   df1 df2 df3 ## for common genes

gene1  df1 df2  ## for genes which arr not across all the combination 
gene2
```

In the first case the solution works as the **gene3** is preset in all the case but fails when it is present in only 2 condition.

So how do I find out all the possible combination where the genes are present in different possible combination.

For example if **gene3** is present in all three so it is reported but gene1 and gene2 are present in `df1` and `df2` but these are not reported.

So I would like to see if a group of genes present in all condition which is not possible most likely but all the possible combination where its is present

My actual dataframes are named as such which is in a list

```
names(result_abd)
 [1] "M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages" "M0_vs_M2_TCGA_stages" "M0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages" "M0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages" "M0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages" "M1_vs_M2_TCGA_stages"
 [7] "M1_vs_M3_TCGA_stages" "M1_vs_M4_TCGA_stages" "M1_vs_M5_TCGA_stages" "M2_vs_M3_TCGA_stages" "M2_vs_M4_TCGA_stages" "M2_vs_M5_TCGA_stages"
[13] "M3_vs_M4_TCGA_stages" "M3_vs_M5_TCGA_stages" "M4_vs_M5_TCGA_stages"
>
```

So I would have like 15 columns for each dataframe

I ran your code the output is as such

```
dput(head(a))
structure(list(gene = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000971", 
"ENSG00000002726", "ENSG00000003989", "ENSG00000005381", "ENSG00000006534"
), dfM0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages = c("M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", 
"M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", 
"M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages"), dfM0_vs_M2_TCGA_stages = c(NA, "M0_vs_M2_TCGA_stages", 
"M0_vs_M2_TCGA_stages", NA, "M0_vs_M2_TCGA_stages", NA), dfM0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages = c("M0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", 
"M0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", NA, "M0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", 
NA), dfM0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages = c("M0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA, "M0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", 
NA, "M0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages"), dfM0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c("M0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", 
NA, "M0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA, "M0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages"
), dfM1_vs_M2_TCGA_stages = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), dfM1_vs_M3_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "M1_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", NA), dfM1_vs_M4_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
"M1_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA, NA, NA, NA), dfM1_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
NA, "M1_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA, NA, NA), dfM2_vs_M3_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "M2_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", NA), dfM2_vs_M4_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
"M2_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA, NA, NA, NA), dfM2_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
NA, "M2_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA, "M2_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA), 
    dfM3_vs_M4_TCGA_stages = c(NA, "M3_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA, 
    NA, "M3_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA), dfM3_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
    "M3_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA, NA, "M3_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA
    ), dfM4_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c(NA, NA, "M4_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", 
    NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Dataframe format

```
 A tibble: 6 × 16
  gene            dfM0_vs_M1_TCGA… dfM0_vs_M2_TCGA… dfM0_vs_M3_TCGA… dfM0_vs_M4_TCGA… dfM0_vs_M5_TCGA… dfM1_vs_M2_TCGA… dfM1_vs_M3_TCGA… dfM1_vs_M4_TCGA…
  <chr>           <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
1 ENSG00000000003 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… NA               M0_vs_M3_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M4_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M5_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA              
2 ENSG00000000971 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M2_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M3_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA               NA               M1_vs_M4_TCGA_s…
3 ENSG00000002726 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M2_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M3_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M4_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M5_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA              
4 ENSG00000003989 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA              
5 ENSG00000005381 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M2_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M3_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M4_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M5_TCGA_s… NA               M1_vs_M3_TCGA_s… NA              
6 ENSG00000006534 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… NA               NA               M0_vs_M4_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M5_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA
```

Now this is what i wanted. The next step as an example I would like to see

If I take this gene `ENSG00000000971` is present in 7 comparison but not in others where its is reported as `NA`.How do I group them.

Like making another data frame with those genes lets say are present in multiple comparison and not include wherever this is `NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly how you want your ourput formatted (several index columns or one column containing a string or a list column).  But here's one option.  I start by combining your list of data fames into a single data frame, with an index indicating the source.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3) 

dfList %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="df") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=df, names_prefix="df", values_from=df) 
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   genes  df1   df2   df3  
   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 gene1  1     2     NA   
 2 gene3  1     2     3    
 3 gene4  1     NA    3    
 4 gene2  1     2     NA   
 5 gene5  NA    2     NA   
 6 genet  NA    2     NA   
 7 gene6  NA    NA    3    
 8 gdene7 NA    NA    3    
 9 genex  NA    NA    3    
10 gene10 NA    NA    3
```

Addition in response to OP's question below.  (Though note that's actually a new question and really should be a new post.)

```
dfList %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="df") %>% 
  group_by(genes) %>% 
  summarise(minDF=min(df), maxDF=max(df)) %>% 
  filter(minDF == maxDF & maxDF == 3) %>% 
  pull(genes)
[1] "gdene7" "gene10" "gene6"  "genex"
```

Once again, the key is to put all the data into a single data frame.  (And the desired format of the output is not clear.)

Comment: okay so if i have to find a certain genes that is specific to df3 how do i subset it further? ..

Comment: I have added my data to show you the output sorry I was editing my question i would rather make new question will add this question and your response

Comment: I will post that as new one..

Comment: your second solution works absolutely fine, i was having issue with the pull function due to old version of my library ,now it gives me list of genes is it possible to know from which columns is it coming from?