# Segregating genes in rows across different comparison to groups

Tags: r

This was the [solution][1] given to me to find common and unique elements across the rows.

I ran this

```
a <- result_abd %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="df") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=df, names_prefix="df", values_from=df)
```

This gives me output as such

```
dput(head(a))
structure(list(gene = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000971", 
"ENSG00000002726", "ENSG00000003989", "ENSG00000005381", "ENSG00000006534"
), dfM0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages = c("M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", 
"M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages", 
"M0_vs_M1_TCGA_stages"), dfM0_vs_M2_TCGA_stages = c(NA, "M0_vs_M2_TCGA_stages", 
"M0_vs_M2_TCGA_stages", NA, "M0_vs_M2_TCGA_stages", NA), dfM0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages = c("M0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", 
"M0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", NA, "M0_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", 
NA), dfM0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages = c("M0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA, "M0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", 
NA, "M0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M4_TCGA_stages"), dfM0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c("M0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", 
NA, "M0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA, "M0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", "M0_vs_M5_TCGA_stages"
), dfM1_vs_M2_TCGA_stages = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), dfM1_vs_M3_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "M1_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", NA), dfM1_vs_M4_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
"M1_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA, NA, NA, NA), dfM1_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
NA, "M1_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA, NA, NA), dfM2_vs_M3_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "M2_vs_M3_TCGA_stages", NA), dfM2_vs_M4_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
"M2_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA, NA, NA, NA), dfM2_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
NA, "M2_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA, "M2_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA), 
    dfM3_vs_M4_TCGA_stages = c(NA, "M3_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA, 
    NA, "M3_vs_M4_TCGA_stages", NA), dfM3_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c(NA, 
    "M3_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA, NA, "M3_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", NA
    ), dfM4_vs_M5_TCGA_stages = c(NA, NA, "M4_vs_M5_TCGA_stages", 
    NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The dataframe looks like this

```
A tibble: 6 × 16
  gene            dfM0_vs_M1_TCGA… dfM0_vs_M2_TCGA… dfM0_vs_M3_TCGA… dfM0_vs_M4_TCGA… dfM0_vs_M5_TCGA… dfM1_vs_M2_TCGA… dfM1_vs_M3_TCGA… dfM1_vs_M4_TCGA…
  <chr>           <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
1 ENSG00000000003 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… NA               M0_vs_M3_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M4_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M5_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA              
2 ENSG00000000971 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M2_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M3_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA               NA               M1_vs_M4_TCGA_s…
3 ENSG00000002726 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M2_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M3_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M4_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M5_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA              
4 ENSG00000003989 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA              
5 ENSG00000005381 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M2_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M3_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M4_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M5_TCGA_s… NA               M1_vs_M3_TCGA_s… NA              
6 ENSG00000006534 M0_vs_M1_TCGA_s… NA               NA               M0_vs_M4_TCGA_s… M0_vs_M5_TCGA_s… NA               NA               NA              
# … with 7 more variables: dfM1_vs_M5_TCGA_stages <chr>, dfM2_vs_M3_TCGA_stages <chr>, dfM2_vs_M4_TCGA_stages <chr>, dfM2_vs_M5_TCGA_stages <chr>,
```

Here I would like to see the next downstream filtering is this. if I take `ENSG00000000003` and `ENSG00000000971`.

This gene `ENSG00000000003` present in column no 1,3,4,5
Similarly `ENSG00000000971` present in column no 1,2,3,8,11,13,14.

Now there would be lots of genes which would be like this.

My objective is to segregate the genes and columns  into as such that there would be no `NA` in in only those data-frames.

Expected output made in different google [sheets][2]

**UPDATES**

```
ab <- result_abd %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="df") %>% 
  group_by(gene) %>% 
  summarise(minDF=min(df), maxDF=max(df))
```

I get something like this

```
gene    minDF   maxDF
<chr>   <chr>   <chr>
ENSG00000000003 1   5
ENSG00000000938 10  9
ENSG00000000971 1   8
```

What does 1 and 5 means for the first gene ? does it mean it is present in 1 and the 5th column of the data-frame?
[1]: [How to find common and unique elements across multiple data-frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560613/how-to-find-common-and-unique-elements-across-multiple-data-frames)
[2]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T3wnPjsWS4RqSi5-eRoJurqeW6rdrthI/edit#gid=1306398905

Comment: I don't understand what your desired out output would be.  What does "segregate the genes and columns into as such that there would be no NA in in only those data-frames" mean?  Can you give your expected output based on your sample input data?

Comment: okay will make it manually ..and post it..

Comment: @Limey It was difficult to make the data in R so i made it in excel google excel as different sheet MY EXPECTED output as an example I have give from M0 to M5 comparisons I hope this will help you for giving the solution. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T3wnPjsWS4RqSi5-eRoJurqeW6rdrthI/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113399850841174925248&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @Limey your previous solutions works the second one you gave which pulls out gene only thing which Im not able to find is these are coming from which column .

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with tidyverse but in base R you could do something like:

If `a` is your data as a `matrix` then

```
patterns <- apply(a, 1, function(x) paste(which(!is.na(x)), collapse=","))

lapply(unique(patterns), function(p) {
 a[patterns == p, strsplit(p, ",")[[1]] ]
})
```

Comment: let  me run it first will update..The error I got is this `Error in `vectbl_as_col_location()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `1`, `2`, `4`, `5`, and `6` don't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> `